# Arraylist in Java removing elements

Tags: java, arraylist

I have 2 ArrayList, one containing `String`s, the other `Integer`s. The `list2` contains indices of elements of `list1`.

Now I need to remove all the elements from `list1` whose index is in `list2`. Any ideas?

```
ArrayList<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>(); 
list1.add("a");
list1.add("b");
list1.add("c");
list1.add("d");
list1.add("e");
list1.add("f");

ArrayList<Integer> list2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
list2.add(1);
list2.add(4);
list2.add(2);
```

The problem here is, you cannot remove from original `list1` as the index will keep changing. I tried creating a temp `HashMap` to store the array index and `String` relation.

I iterate over `list2` and map. When I found a matching key=index, I skipped that. Else I put `String` element in new list.

Any better suggestions?

Comment: What is your end goal with these two lists? Having two parallel lists is usually a sign that you need to create a new class, holding one element of both lists.

Comment: @JBNizet Just a question I was asked in an interview and was thinking how to implement it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This solution assumes that null is not a valid value in `list1`.

You could iterate through `list2`, and for each index you get to, set the corresponding value in `list1` to null.  Then remove all the nulls from `list1` at the end.  This will work even if there are duplicate elements in `list2`, which jlordo's solution would have difficulty with.

```
for(Integer index : list2){
    list1.set(index,null);
}
list1.removeAll(Collections.singleton(null));
```

Answer (score 4):

Sort `list2` and delete items from `list1` starting at the highest index given in `list2`.
That way your other relevant indexes in `list1` wont change.

You could do it like this:

```
    Collections.sort(list2, Collections.reverseOrder());
    for (Integer i : list2) {
        list1.remove((int) i);
    }
```

**EDIT:**

As pointed out by David Wallace in his comment, above approach only works if there are no duplicates in `list2`. You can get rid of duplicates by adding the following line before the code posted above:

```
list2 = new ArrayList<>(new HashSet<>(list2));
```

Comment: hmm..so reverse sort list2 and remove from list1..interesting!

Comment: It'll solve the problem you are currently facing. If the order of `list2` is important to you, first create a copy of it and sort that one.

Comment: This won't work if there are any duplicated indexes in list2.  You need to remove duplicates before you start.

Comment: @DavidWallace: good point! See my edit... (Also, +1 for your answer)

Answer (score 0):

If you just care about insertion order, something like a `LinkedHashMap` work better for this. But, in order to determine an index, you would have to iterate over the list until you found the element you wanted:

```
int n = 0;
for (String value : linkedMap) {
  if (value.equals(valueToSearch)) {
    break;
   }
   ++n;
}
// n == index now
```

If you frequently need the indexes, then you probably just want 2 Maps. One that holds indexe -> String and the other holds String -> index. Just make sure you insert and remove from both maps at the same time.

Answer (score -3):

Used for BaseAdapter and getView() method inside code write down and particular onClickListner imlement and try this out this code,

```
mArrayList.remove(position);
notifyDataSetChanged();
```